# Saving the default value of Form Group in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am actually looking for a way to saving the default value of the Form group which is as below in my code

```
infoGroup = {
    field1:             new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, Validators.required),
    field2:             new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    field3:             new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, Validators.required),
    field4:             new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }),
    field3:             new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }),
} 

infoForm = new FormGroup({ ... this.infoGroup})
```

I am passing this value to a method `markAllFieldForBrowseOnly` that makes the field enable and disable based on the condition

```
let formValue = this.infoForm;
if(condition) {
   this.service.markAllFieldForBrowseOnly(formValue);
}
```

The signature of the `markAllFieldForBrowseOnly` method is as below

```
markAllFieldForBrowseOnly(formGroup : FormGroup, button : any) {
   formGroup.disable();
}
```

But there is no way, we can save the initial disable value of the the form control to be be enable or disable.

I tried saving the value in a variable name formValue above. But that does not help.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: you want to access disabled value?

Comment: Yes the values in disabled

Comment: you can not use the spread operator to create the form (the spread operator copy the values, but not the functions itself). create a function that return a formGroup e.g. `defaultForm(){return new FormGroup({field1:new FormControl(...)})}` and equal your form `this.infoForm=this.defaultForm()`. Other aproach is save in an array of object {field:'field',value:'',enabled:''} and use a forEach over the array